# admob verifying my identity failed with error : We couldn't submit your form yet. Please fix the fields above

Tags: admob

I was asked to provide a code to verify my ID and address, by my country there is no such thing like post service like west, so after 4 time which I tried to get the code, now I have to fill a form to verify my ID and do the KYC.

when I submit the form I get an error which does not says meaningful but in the console I found this error, can somebody help my to solve this issue

```
0: "FRD_INVALID:signal_user_country:8;"
1: "FRD_INVALID:signal_adsense_tier:8;"
```

[image: Image to show console]